# Following the Mapbox beginners tutorial returns a "Manifest merger failed" error

Tags: android, gradle, build, mapbox, manifest

I have started a new project and the only thing I have added is the dependency for Mapbox SDK. When I build the project it produces the following output:

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-19:19 to override.
```

Here's my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.xxxx.xxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.1.0'
}
```

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.xxx.xxxxxxx">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I have not added anything else to this project, and have followed the Mapbox tutorial by the letter. I don't see why this is occurring. I am not very familiar with Gradle so I am sorry if this is an obvious question :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this merger fail might be because the Mapbox Maps SDK for Android is using AndroidX and you're still using AppCompat (`support:appcompat` etc.) dependencies.

Transition your project to AndroidX? https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

and/or at least see what happens when you add two AndroidX-related flags to your `gradle.properties` file?: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#migrate_an_existing_project_using_android_studio